# Shuffled array uncaught exception

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsmutablearray

Im using four buttons and shuffle the button tag value to view different values on each click,  Since i show the value of button from array, While am trying to shuffle the tag value i got following error.

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:]: index 16 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

My code for shuffling the array of tag value,

```
words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",@"4", nil] ;

 NSUInteger count = [questar count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
    NSInteger nElements = count - i;
    NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [words exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
```

What change should i made??Can any one help me to solve

Comment: where is `count` variable defined?

Comment: @Eimantas Sorry. Now question updated

Comment: What is `questar` comprised of? It seems that `questar` has more elements than `words` (17 vs 4)

Comment: @Aadhira array of images

Comment: @Dev_iOS, Array of images is fine, how many elements it have?

Comment: @Eimantas `questar` contain around 52 images, and am showing each 4 on click in shuffled manner

Comment: Then obviously it will crash, right? Just apply your logic. All the best.

Comment: Do you want to add a new object from quester to words array?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select an image from `quester` first. You created the index `n` to take object from `quester` array no?

```
words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3",@"4", nil] ;

NSUInteger count = [questar count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
{
  // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
  NSInteger nElements = count - i;
  NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;

  currentImage = [questar objectAtIndex:n];

  [words replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:currentImage];
}
```

Or if you want to exchange within the array change `count` as :

```
NSUInteger count = [words count];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[words exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
```

In the above statement, both `i` and `n` should have a value less than the `words` count (here it is 4). Else, you would get exception.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
NSInteger nElements = count - i;
NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
```

Should be changed to:

```
NSInteger nElements = count;
NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements);
```